# Scala: apply function on a collection and yield only some of the results

Tags: scala

Assume that I have an expensive function `f`  and many values in `v`

```
def f(x: Int) = {
  x + 3
}

val v = 0 to 10e7.toInt
```

Now I want to apply `f` on `v` and select some results based on some condition.

I can do it like this

```
v.map(f).filter(_ > 10e7 - 5)
```

But that's not feasible at all because the whole `v.map(f)` will be stored in memory first.

So then other option is to do:

```
for(a <- v if f(a) > 10e7 - 5) yield f(a)
```

But now I need to calculate f twice for some elements which is out of question!

So how can I achieve the filtering without storing the whole result but still get the results. The logic would look like something like this (obviously this is not working):

```
for(a <- v) {
  val b = f(a)
  if(b > 10e7 - 5) yield b
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about an `iterator`?

```
scala> v.iterator.map(f).filter(_ > 10e7 - 5).toVector
res4: Vector[Int] = Vector(99999996, 99999997, 99999998, 99999999, 100000000, 100000001, 100000002, 100000003)
```

or `view`

```
scala>  v.view.map(f).filter(_ > 10e7 - 5).toVector
res5: Vector[Int] = Vector(99999996, 99999997, 99999998, 99999999, 100000000, 100000001, 100000002, 100000003)
```

Both won't create any intermediate collection.

By the way don't look for some magic in for comprehensions, they are just syntactic sugars, you can do roughly equivalen thing with this:

```
scala> (for {
          a <- v.iterator
          fa = f(a)
          if fa > 10e7 - 5
        } yield fa).toVector
res9: Vector[Int] = Vector(99999996, 99999997, 99999998, 99999999, 100000000, 100000001, 100000002, 100000003)
```

If you wouldn't get `iterator` from `v` mapping whole collection would still occur as in your examples that cause `OutOfMemoryError`.